# Altering a returned collection in onBefore hook or similar hook

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to alter (add more fields for each record) a returned collection in onBeforeAction or similar hook?

I have InvoiceHistory collection which I am paginating through. I also want to display as part of each invoice the company name, business address, email address and VAT registration number - and these four fields are stored in another collection. So I would like to add these four fields to each record returned from InvoiceHistory. If there is another way to do it I am open to suggestions. I am using Alethes meteor pagination which loses the helper fields returned in its itemTemplate when you navigate/browse/page to the second  page. Alethes pagination also relies on iron-router, is it maybe possible to achieve what I want with the help of iron-router

========================================================================

@Sean. Thanks. Below is the code that uses meteor publish composite:

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {

 import { publishComposite } from 'meteor/reywood:publish-composite';

 publishComposite('invoicesWithCompanyDetails', function(userId, startingDate,endingDate) {
  return {
   find() {
    // Find purchase history for userId and the two dates that were entered. Note arguments for callback function
    // being used in query.
    return PurchaseHistory.find({Id:userId,transactionDate:{$gte:new Date(decodeURIComponent(startingDate)),
       $lt:new Date(decodeURIComponent(endingDate))}});
   },
   children: [
    {
   
     find() {
      return CompanySharedNumbers.find(
       { _id:"firstOccurrence" },
       { fields: { companyName: 1, companyAddress: 1 } }
      );
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 });
}
```

```js
Router.route('/store/invoices/:_username/:startingDate/:endingDate', { //:_startingDate/:_endingDate
 name: 'invoices',
 template: 'invoices',
 onBeforeAction: function()
 {
  ...
 },
 waitOn: function() {
  var startingDate = this.params.startingDate;
  var endingDate = this.params.endingDate;
  return [Meteor.subscribe('systemInfo'),Meteor.subscribe('testingOn'),Meteor.subscribe('invoicesWithCompanyDetails',startingDate,endingDate)];
 } 
});
```

```js
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(PurchaseHistory, {
 itemTemplate: "invoice",
 availableSettings: {filters: true},
 filters: {},
 route: "/store/invoices/:_username/:startingDate/:endingDate/",
 router: "iron-router",
 routerTemplate: "invoices",
 routerLayout: "main",
 sort: {
  transactionDate: 1
 },
 perPage: 1,
 templateName: "invoices",
 homeRoute:"home"
});
```

Comment: Look at collection transformations https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html also, you might prefer denormalizing...

Comment: I took a look at the transformations; neat, but how do you apply it to alethes pagination collection? Denormalizing will definitely work, but the app I am building already requires a lot of space and I am trying to make it as efficient as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding new fields to all your document. What you could do is to add a helper to load a company document :

```
Template.OneInvoice.helpers({
    loadCompany(companyId){
        return Company.findOne({_id: companyId});
    }
});
```

And use it in your template code:

```
<template name="OneInvoice">
    <p>Invoice id: {{invoice._id}}</p>
    <p>Invoice total: {{invoice.total}}</p>
    {{#let company=(loadCompany invoice.companyId)}}
        <p>Company name: {{company.name}}</p>
        <p>Company business address: {{company.businessAddress}}</p>
    {{/let}}
</template>
```

This way, the code is very simple and easily maintainable.

Comment: I have already tried what you are suggesting. See my comment above on it:  " I am using Alethes meteor pagination which loses the helper fields returned in its itemTemplate when you navigate/browse/page to the second page" If I needed it for one page it would be a great solution. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: I even gave the let statement a try after re-looking at your code. It only displays on the first page as I had before. Sorry, and thanks once more.

Comment: ** So to avoid duplicating what is already written on this page what @Gaetan have here is partially correct. The only thing missing is that the subscription for the collection that contains company details must not be on a particular iron-router route but be global** So in my case Meteor.subscribe('companyAddressNameEmailAndVatNumber') must be global

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this sounds like a job for a [composite publication](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite).

Using a composite publication you can return related data from multiple collections at the same time.

So, you can find all your invoices, then using the company ID stored in the invoice objects you can return the company name and other info from the Companies collection at the same time.

I've used composite publications before for complex data structures and they worked perfectly.

Hope that helps

Comment: It looks like it might work. I'll try it and let you know. I wanted to encourage other folks to make suggestions that is why I did not comment sooner

Comment: Oh by the way other folks your suggestions are still welcomed

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. The pages do not show the company details. Please see my code below

Comment: Can you update your original post with your composite publication code?

And can you install this package: https://github.com/msavin/Mongol

so you can see when data is successfully being sent to a view

Comment: A million thank you's for the tip. No the data is not being sent to the view

Comment: Ok, our 'children' part of the composite publication isn't correct. You aren't passing any arguments to the child publication.

What is 'firstOccurence'?